# While loop for converting Celsius to Fahrenheit Java

Tags: java

```
import java.util.*;
public class lab1
{
public static void main(String args [])
{
  double Fahrenheit;
  int celsius = 0;
  while (celsius <= 15);
  Fahrenheit= (9.0/5.0 * celsius) + 32;
  System.out.println( "Fahrenheit:" + Fahrenheit + "celsius:" + celsius);
  celsius++;
  }
  }
```

I have a problem with this program. I get no compile errors, but when I run it it doesn't display the results. Celsius temperature is given and I need to add 1 every time I find the Fahrenheit. Also: how do I show the results in two columns, like in the example below (instead of math and English I want to put Fahrenheit and Celsius)

```
Math scores            English scores
0                         0
2                         2
3                         7
4                         10
2                          0
2                          1
```

Answer (score 0):

The semicolon after your while loop is causing your program to infinite loop, which is why nothing's printing.

You should change `while (celsius <= 15);` into `while (celsius <= 15)` and also surround the three lines after the while loop in curly braces.

Comment: when I run the java my results show the words Fahrenheit and celsius many times. Is there a way for me to make a column specifically for fahrenheit and another for celsius THAT DISPLAYS THOSE TERMS ONCE AND THEN THE RESULTS RIGHT UNDER THEM?

Comment: Just print the first row ("Fahrenheit\tCelsius") before the loop. Then, inside the loop, just print the values (Fahrenheit + "\t" + celsius).

Answer (score 0):

Your `while` loop had no block to operate. It should be like this:

```
import java.util.*;
public class Lab1 {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    double fahrenheit, celsius = 0;
    while (celsius <= 15) {
      fahrenheit = (9.0/5.0 * celsius) + 32;
      System.out.println( "Fahrenheit:" + fahrenheit + "Celsius:" + celsius);
      celsius++;
    }
  }
}
```

Every loop in Java have its own body (operation block), it will iterate the work it has to do inside this block; yours only does nothing so it loops into infinity.